# Unable to assign nn.Module class to self.encoder in another nn.Module class

Tags: python, pytorch

In the code shown below, I would like to create an `Encoder` class and then assign it into `self.encoder` in `ComponentEmbedding` class. However, when i try to access `ComponentEmbedding().encoder`, the value is still `None`. Anyone help?

Note: I need to preserve `encoder = None`, in case `create_encoder = False`.

Code:

```
import torch.nn as nn

class Encoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        pass
    
    def forward(self, x):
        pass

class ComponentEmbedding(nn.Module):
    
    encoder = None
    
    def __init__(self, create_encoder=True):
        super().__init__()
        if create_encoder:
            self.init_encoder()
        
    def forward(self, x):
        pass
    
    def init_encoder(self):
        self.encoder = Encoder()

print(ComponentEmbedding().encoder)
```

Output:

```
None
```

Expected Output:

```
Encoder()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are initializing `encoder` as a class attribute with value `None` whereas it should be an instance attribute:

```
class Encoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
    
    def forward(self, x):
        pass

class ComponentEmbedding(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, create_encoder=True):
        super().__init__()
        if create_encoder:
            self.init_encoder()
        
    def forward(self, x):
        pass
    
    def init_encoder(self):
        self.encoder = Encoder()
```

Then:

```
>>> ComponentEmbedding().encoder
Encoder()
```